# Getting Maximum call stack size exceeded on Fileupload

Tags: jquery

I want to open window to upload image on button click, but I'm getting this error:

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceededEximum

```js
jQuery('.upload-wrap-div').click(function(e) {
  jQuery("input[type='file']").trigger('click');
})

jQuery("input[type='file']").change(function() {
  jQuery('#val').text(this.value.replace(/C:\\fakepath\\/i, ''))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group files text-center upload-wrap-div" ref="fileform">
  <input type="file" name="img" multiple style="display:none">
  <span id='val'></span>
  <a class="btn" id='button'>Upload Photo</a>
  <h6>DRAG & DROP FILE HERE</h6>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because you're triggering a `click` event within a `click` event handler, and therefore creating an infinite loop.

To fix this change the container `div` to a `label`. That way you don't need either  `click` handler because it's default `label` behaviour to put focus on the inner form control. Try this:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $("input[type='file']").change(function() {
    $('#val').text(this.value.replace(/C:\\fakepath\\/i, ''));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="form-group files text-center upload-wrap-div" ref="fileform">
  <input type="file" name="img" multiple style="display:none">
  <span id='val'></span>
  <a class="btn" id='button'>Upload Photo</a>
  <h6>DRAG &amp; DROP FILE HERE</h6>
</label>
```

Also note the aliased use of `$` in the document.ready handler. This avoids having to use the `jQuery` keyword in your code, making it less verbose.